# TinyMCE textarea character limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have multiple tinyMCE textareas on one page and I want to limit the characters only in the textareas with the class "shorttext".

here is my code:

```
// TINYMCE CONFIG
    tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      height: 400,
      plugins: [
        'searchreplace',
        'code'
      ],
      toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | fontsizeselect bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
      fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt'
    });         
    // TINYMCE
```

How can I separately set a character limit only to the textareas with the class "shorttext"?

Comment: maybe this will help : http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How_to_limit_number_of_characters/words

Comment: thanks for your quick answer david but unfortunately it does not help or maybe I just dont get it. :)

Comment: you could use a tinymce keydown handler and block the insertion of new content in case the character limit is reached

Comment: ok and how can i do this only for the textareas with the class "shorttext"?